# computing partial area under a curve at specified intervals

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I need to integrate the area under a curve, but rather than integrating the entire area under the curve at once, I would like to integrate partial areas at a specified interval of 5m. I.e, I would like to know the area under the curve from 0-5m, 5 - 10m, 10 - 15m, etc.

However, the spacing between my x values is irregular (i.e., it does not go [1, 2, 3, 4...] but rather could go, [1, 1.2, 2, 2.3, 3.1, 4...]. So I can't go by index number but rather need to go by values, and I want to create intervals of every 5 meters.

```
# Here is a sample of the data set (which I do NOT use in the function below, just an example of how irregular the spacing between x values is)
x = [0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.3, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10, 12, 12.5, 12.7, 13, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5]
y = [0, -0.44, -0.83, -0.91, -1.10, -1.16, -1.00, -1.02, -1.05, -1.0, -0.94, - 0.89, -1, -1.39, -1.44, -1.88, -1.9, -1.94, -2.03, -1.9]
```

I've created a function to get the partial area based on one specific interval (5<x<10), but I need to figure out how to do this for the entire dataframe.

```
from scipy.integrate import simps 

def partial_area (y, x):
    x =df.query('5 <= X <= 10')['X']
    y =df.query('5 <= X <= 10')['Z']
    area = simps(y,x)
    return (area)

area = partial_area(y,x)
```

I'm stuck on the best way to go about this, as I'm not sure how to create intervals by data values rather than index.